# Cython: using distutils to compile C++

Tags: python, c++, cython, distutils

I am trying to wrap some C++ neural network code, so that I have:

```
numpy -> double* -> armadillo
```

Anyhow, I am getting the typical:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function
```

It is obviously something wrong in my distutils configuration. Here is a MEW of my project in case someone can finger down the bug:

setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python build_ext --inplace
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# to run:
# python setup.py build_ext --inplace

from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name='My Test',
    ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
        "test",
        sources=["nnet_wrap.pyx", "nnet.cpp"],
        libraries = ['armadillo'],
        language="c++",
)))
```

nnet_wrap.pyx

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "nnet.h":
    void nnet_fit(int D, int N, double* X, double* Y)


class WrapNN:
    def nnet_fit(self, np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] X):
        X = np.ascontiguousarray(X)
        cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1] y = np.zeros((len(X),), dtype=np.double)
        nnet_fit(X.shape[1], X.shape[0], &X[0,0], &y[0])
        return y
```

nnet.h

```
void nnet_fit(int D, int N, double* X, double* Y);
```

nnet.cpp

```
#include <armadillo>
using namespace arma;

void nnet_fit(int D, int N, double* X, double* Y)
{
    mat _X(X, N, D, false);
    // do work
    vec _Y;  // results
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        Y[i] = _Y[i];
}
```

I know it is a little hacky. Anyhow, it compiles fine and generates a `test.so` file, but then it fails to import:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
$ python
>>> import test
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (inittest)
```

**EDIT:** some more information as requested:

```
$ readelf -Ws test.so | grep init
   118: 0000000000003168     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    9 _init
   123: 000000000000ab90   160 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   11 _ZN4arma3MatIdE9init_coldEv
   126: 0000000000009ae0  4211 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 initnnet_wrap
    42: 00000000000036e0    79 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 _ZL30__Pyx_CyFunction_init_defaultsP22__pyx_CyFunctionObject
   202: 000000000020f3e0     1 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   24 _ZStL8__ioinit
   211: 000000000020dce0     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
   306: 0000000000009ae0  4211 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 initnnet_wrap
   330: 000000000000ab90   160 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   11 _ZN4arma3MatIdE9init_coldEv
   344: 0000000000003168     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    9 _init
```

By the way, my Cython version is the one from Ubuntu 14.04 which could be slightly outdated. I know some syntax has been changed from distutils. Tell me if you think that could be a problem.

```
$ dpkg -s cython | grep Version
Version: 0.20.1+git90-g0e6e38e-1ubuntu2
```

Comment: what does `readelf -Ws test.so | grep init` (or `nm -gC test.so | grep init`) say?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini added to the post! ps: if I change the name of the shared object from "test" to "nnet_wrap", it can import. I will have to test it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module that is being built is called `nnet_wrap`, but the output file is called `test.so`. This is confirmed by the fact that your `test.so` contains a symbol named `initnnet_wrap` (Python instead is incorrectly looking for `inittest`).

In your extension definition, replace `'test'` with `'nnet_wrap'`, so that Python can find the right symbol.

```
ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
    "test",
#    ^^^^
    sources=["nnet_wrap.pyx", "nnet.cpp"],
#             ^^^^^^^^^
    libraries = ['armadillo'],
    language="c++",
))
```